# TreeView WPF with multiple levels

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have the following class:

```
class Component
{
    ComponentType ComponentType {get; set;}
    string Name {set; set;}
    List<Component> SubComponents {get; set;}
}

enum ComponentType
{
    Feature,
    Role
}
```

And on my VM a `List<Component> AllComponents {get;}` that contains *all* of my components, regardless of `ComponentType`.

I would like to, without having to separate my `Component` by `ComponentType`, display them in a `TreeView` as such:

```
Roles
    ComponentA
    ComponentB
        ComponentC
        ComponentD
    ComponentE
Features
    ComponentF
    ComponentG
        ComponentH
    ComponentI
```

But I'm really unsure how to do this in WPF without having to create two separate `List<Component>` or a `Dictionary<ComponentType, Component>` (which I would also like to avoid).

So pretty simple question, is there a way to achieve this with just XAML?

PS: All `SubComponents` will always have the same `ComponentType` as their parents.

Comment: Have you tried to use a `GroupStyle`?

Comment: @LittleBit I haven't. Can you provide an example of that? If it works I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: Ops, i meant `Collectionviewsource`. I'll provide an example as answer.

Answer (score 0):

`AllComponens` should contain two hierarchical `Component` objects  - with the names "Roles" and "Features" - that represent the root of each tree.

The "Roles" object's `SubComponents` property should then contain three other `Component` objects (ComponentA, B and E), and the "Features" objects's `SubComponents` property should also contain three child objects (F, G, and I), e.g.:

```
public List<Component> AllComponents { get; } = new List<Component>()
{
    new Component(){ Name = "Roles", SubComponents = new List<Component>(){ new Component() { Name = "A" }, new Component() { Name = "B" }, new Component() { Name = "E" } } },
    new Component(){ Name = "Features",SubComponents = new List<Component>(){ new Component() { Name = "F" }, new Component() { Name = "G" }, new Component() { Name = "I" } } }
};
```

If you organize your data like this in your view model, you could use the following TreeView to represent your hierarchy:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding AllComponents}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SubComponents}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I´ve done this with a TreeviewItemModel:

```
public class TreeViewItemViewModel : BindableBase
    {

        private string _name;
        private TreeViewItemViewModel _parent;
        private List<TreeViewItemViewModel> _childern;


        public TreeViewItemViewModel(TreeViewItemViewModel parent, string name)
        {
            _parent = parent;
            _name = name;

            _childern = new List<TreeViewItemViewModel>();
        }



        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _name;
            }
        }

        public TreeViewItemViewModel Parent
        {
            get
            {
                return _parent;
            }
        }

        public List<TreeViewItemViewModel> Children
        {
            get
            {
                return _childern;
            }
        }

        public void AddChild(TreeViewItemViewModel c)
        {
            _childern.Add(c);
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Children));
        }

    }
```

then you just need:

```
            <TreeView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
              ItemsSource="{Binding TreeItemsUserSearch}"
              IsEnabled="{Binding TreeEnabled}">
                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <b:TreeViewSelectedItemBehavior SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTreeItemUserSearch}" />
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

                <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            </TreeView>
```

In your ViewModel you only need to have:

```
private List<TreeViewItemViewModel> _treeItemsUserSearch;


public List<TreeViewItemViewModel> TreeItemsUserSearch
{
    get
    {
        return _treeItemsUserSearch;
    }
}
```

then you can create every strukture you need